# Update state only on OK, revert back to previous state on CANCEL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app similar to what is shown in this codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/eatery-forked-t44bx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Clicking the `Menu` at the bottom center of the page renders the `MenuFilter` component.

The way I have it now, checking the checkbox immediately updates the checked items. This is good from a user interface point of you.
User gets instant feedback on what he is clicking on (what is getting un-clicked if something is getting un-clicked).

The problem with though is that the OK/Cancel button loose there use. In other words, after making changes to the selection, if the user decides that we does not want any of these new selection & rather revert back to old selection (the one before the Menu button was clicked), he cannot do that because all the states have been updated (updating happens as the check boxes are being clicked).

How to update the state ONLY if OK (currently only CANCLE button is working, so you can consider that) button is clicked. However, the check-marks should none the less change as the user is clicking them.

Is there a way to do this other than creating a 'temporary' state (I don't want to do this) to update the visual changes & only when a button is clicked, the changes are done one the data.

Comment: You have to use a temporary state inside the modal, there's no alternative.

Comment: oh! ok. I was hoping for an easier solution

Comment: You could also store your initial value (when you open the menu) and re-apply it to state if the user decides to click on the `cancel` button. That way you do update the state but cancel won't lose its functionality.

Comment: @MazharZandsalimi This is what I ended up doing. I maintain the state in parent component & then pass the state & a handler to update the state to child component. In the child component, create a tempstate who's initial value is parent state & the check boxes are also update based on the temp state.  On clicking OK the parent state will be updated with tempstate, on clicking cancel, the state is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `checkedItems` to a local state of the `MenuFilter` component, and pass it as an argument on `onClick`. That way, when you open the modal, the component mounts again and the state should return to its default.
Something like:

```
export const MenuFilter = ({ onClick, onCheck }) => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState(["allItems"])

  return (
    <button onClick={() => onClick(checkedItems)}>Cancel</button>
  )
}
```

**Edit**: You'll still need some sort of state to handle the data on the parent component, but you won't have to manually handle resetting the data.